Replace battery by DC source (USB 5V)
I bought a Bluetooth audio receiver which is powered by 3.7V Li-ion battery. I tried to replace the battery source to a USB 5V with a buck converter and I managed to achieve it, here is my work around.

I cut my old micro-USB cable and solder +5V and GND wire on input of buck converter.

Adjust buck converter output to 3.7V
Solder buck converter output on circuit battery+, battery-

That's all, the receiver works fine by far, but I have 2 problems.

Initially, it only works when the USB is connected to a USB charger. I would like to plug it into a power bank instead. However, when I connect it to my power bank and turn it on, the receiver starts working, but the power bank shuts down within 5 seconds. I guess that protection mechanism was triggered.
When my cellphone connects to the receiver, why do the remaining battery level change randomly, varying between 10% and 80%. But it seems not a big problem.

So, I am looking for a way that I can power my modified receiver by a power bank, thanks!

Some powerbanks automatically shutoff if not enough current is drawn, you can include a resistor in parallel to drain the power bank faster so it doesn't turn off (or get one without this annoying function for small electronics)
